# Generating random matrices with sum and maximality constraints

Tags: probability, random-generation, random-matrix

I'd like to generate a random square matrix such that the rows are normalized to one and the diagonal elements are the maximum of their column. If there an efficient way to sample these matrices uniformly?

$2 \times 2$ matrices are straightforward to create. The first column is generated by sampling two independent uniforms from $[0,1]$ and moving the maximum to the first entry. The second column is then the complement of the first. My attempts to follow an analogous procedure in higher dimensions feel very ad-hoc, and most troublesomely, give a very different distribution for the final complemented column than the others. Is some type of rejection sampling going to be my best bet?

The motivation is to generate likelihood matrices, with the rows being states of the world and columns being observed signals. Each signal is most likely to occur in its corresponding state, but isn't necessarily the most likely signal in that state.

**Edit:** The exact distribution doesn't matter, other than it seem natural. I would like to avoid the diagonal also being maximal for the rows though.

Here is my own previous ah-hoc attempt.

```
gen.likelihood.matrix <- function(T){
    # T: Number of states

    mat <- matrix(runif(T^2), nrow=T) # Intialize with uniform variates
    diag(mat) <- 1 # To guarantee diag is max in column

    candidate.mat <- matrix(nrow=T, ncol=T)
    # Loop to check for constraint satisfaction
    for(k in 1:100){
        weights <- runif(T-1)
        weights <- weights / sum(weights)

        for(i in 1:T){
            # Rescale columns
            candidate.mat[i,-T] <- mat[i,-T] * weights
            # Replace last column with complement to meet row constraint
            candidate.mat[i,T] <- 1 - sum(candidate.mat[i,-T])
        }

        # Does the last column meet the maximality constraint?
        if(candidate.mat[T,T] > max(candidate.mat[-T,T])){
            # Shuffle to minimize the distortion from last column
            reorder <- sample(1:T,T)
            return(candidate.mat[reorder,reorder])
        }
    }

    # Recurse to get new initial values if necessary
    return(genLikeliMatrix(T))
}
```

This works in terms of giving me matrices efficiently, but I get a weird bimodal distribution on the diagonal due to how I handle the last column.
[image: Distribution of diagonal elements]

Comment: Do the columns have to sum to one also?

Comment: It doesn't have to be doubly stochastic.

Comment: Uniformly *in what metric*?

Comment: @whuber +1. Perhaps uniformity in a rigorous sense isn't actually what's desired, though, just that the diagonal elements and off-diagonal elements are identically distributed? That seems like a simpler problem, albeit one with multiple answers.

Comment: @whuber The precise distribution or sense of uniformity doesn't matter. I'm after something that seems natural more than anything else.

Comment: Blake, your comment about rejection sampling to @Seth's reply suggested you had a specific distribution of matrices in mind. Perhaps you would like to reconsider Seth's approach, then?

Comment: @bnaul: The diagonal and off-diagonal entries cannot have the same marginal distribution (modulo the trivial case) since the diagonal is greater than the off-diagonal entries in the same column. In other words, almost surely larger random variables are also stochastically larger.

Comment: The maximum of a uniform(0,1) is beta(n,1) where n is the sample size of the uniform. The diagonal could be drawn from beta? then fill in the uniforms with rejection.

Comment: @bnaul: (Maybe by your previous comment, you were saying that the diagonal entries all have a common marginal distribution and that, separately, the off-diagonal entries shared a common marginal?)

Comment: Several related questions (none with satisfactory answers): (**1**) [How to sample uniformly from an intersection of simplices?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12645), (**2**) [Random matrices with constraints on row and column length](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17633), (**3**) [Generating random matrices with specific equality constraints](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19173), (**4**) [How to generate a bounded random correlation matrix?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10450)

Comment: @whuber Maybe I'm using "rejection sampling" wrong. The answer by Seth often violates my constraints. I would like to avoid generating a matrix, checking if it meets the constraints, and regenerating if not. A quick check in R shows I reject ~20,000 times for a `7x7` matrix.

Comment: Evidently you can't let the diagonal elements have the same distributions as the non-diagonal elements. Do you have any restriction on the relationships between the diagonal distributions and the off-diagonal distributions?

Comment: It seems like this and maybe other of the 'random matrix subject to constraints' questions could be computed by simulating raw data and computing whatever the statistic the matrix is supposed to be?

Comment: @whuber I don't have any restrictions on that relationship. The distribution induced by rejection sampling with Seth's suggestion is roughly what I'm looking for, but that is infeasible for anything larger than 8x8. I'm looking for a direct method both for efficiency and transparency.

Answer (score 4):

OK, to move these efforts along (but with some diffidence) I offer this approach: generate the diagonal elements first.  Make them large *constants*.  Generate all off-diagonal elements iid according to any (non-negative) distribution you want.  Normalize rows.  Check the column-max condition.  Repeat if violated.

By making the initial constants sufficiently large, the expected number of repetitions can be made small.

Clearly the diagonal elements are iid, the non-diagonal elements are iid, but (of course) the two distributions differ.

Here's some code to play with.

```
n <- 8                                     # Matrix dimension
y <- rep(1 + 3/sqrt(n),n)                  # A large constant compared to entries in x
x <- matrix(runif(n^2), ncol=n)            # Here, uniform distributions off diagonal
x[cbind(1:n,1:n)] <- y                     # (Paste in the diagonal)
z <- t(apply(x, 1, function(u) u/sum(u)))  # Normalize the rows
which(1:n != apply(z, 2, which.max))       # Find all columns violating the conditions
```

(One hopes for `integer(0)` as the output; otherwise, indexes of columns whose maxima are not diagonal will be output.)  I have experimented with `n` ranging from 3 through 300.

It's instructive to plot the columns:

```
plot(z[1,], type="n")
apply(z, 2, function(u) lines(u, col=(256*runif(1))))
```

Comment: Normalizing the rows faster and cleaner: `z <- x/rowSums(x)`

Answer (score 2):

First, I would generate a matrix $M$ such that $M_{ij}$ is exponentially distributed with mean $\mu$ for all $i \ne j$ or $0$ otherwise.

Then, calculate your matrix
\begin{align}
X_{ij} &= \frac{e^{-M_{ij}}}{\sum_je^{-M_{ij}}}
\end{align}

To efficiently sample from a categorical distribution (a list of probabilities totalling 1), just build a Huffman tree using the probabilities of each outcome keeping track of the total probability in descendants to the left of each node.  Sample from a uniform distribution, and find the leaf node whose cdf is the smallest one larger than your sampled value.  (This has an amortized cost of the entropy of your categorical distribution.)

Comment: This guarantees the diagonal elements are maximal in the columns, but normalizes across the columns rather than the rows. If the normalization is done across rows, then the maximality condition is usually not satisfied. I don't want the diagonal to be maximal in the rows generally, only in the columns.

Answer (score 0):

First generate random rows then divide each row by its sum so you get them to sum to one. Then order the rows a particular way, in the first row you want the row that contains the element in its first position that is the max of column 1. So, in the nth row you want the row that has the max of the nth column.

Comment: The problem is that the row with the maximum of the first column might also have the maximum of one of the other columns. This might be a starting point for rejection sampling, but I'm wondering if a more direct way exists.

Answer (score 0):

Just generate each row from a [Dirichlet distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) then reorder if needed to put the largest value on the diagonal (or choose the parameters such that the largest is likely to be on the diagonal).

Comment: As noted in the question and in comments to other answers, the OP wants the *rows* to sum to one, but the diagonal to be maximal in its respective *column*. Your parenthetical comment paired with a rejection sampling scheme and independently distributed rows seems like a little more promising approach depending on the dimensionality of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the same idea of whuber, this time using Dirichlets: the lines of the matrix are independent Dirichlets, with each Dirichlet putting more mass on the corresponding diagonal element.

```
rdirichlet <- function(a) {
    x <- sapply(a, function(a) rgamma(1, a, 1))
    return(x / sum(x))
}

n <- 5
A0 <- 10
a <- matrix(data = 1, nrow = n, ncol = n)
diag(a) <- A0
x <- matrix(nrow = n, ncol = n)
for (i in 1:n) x[i,] <- rdirichlet(a[i,])
```

Reject if `x` does not satisfy the constraints. If the rejection rate is too high, increase the value of `A0`. Here is a sample `x`.

```
> x
            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]        [,5]
[1,] 0.484437196 0.03511667 0.04919437 0.12718905 0.304062711
[2,] 0.008626386 0.76520244 0.03231747 0.02454215 0.169311552
[3,] 0.176631389 0.01971251 0.55780424 0.07952712 0.166324747
[4,] 0.003109732 0.12056624 0.09335086 0.77330892 0.009664246
[5,] 0.037015097 0.02485376 0.04536731 0.05083834 0.841925490
```

P.S. Please, vectorize that pesky `for`.

Comment: *Please, vectorize that pesky* `for`. **Ok**. How's this? `x <- matrix(rgamma(prod(dim(a)),a),ncol(a)); x <- x / rowSums(x)`

Comment: It doesn't matter in this case but the `ncol(a)` should have been `nrow(a)` or `nc=ncol(a)` (either of the last two being equally valid).